# Powershell: How can i install a cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, installation, vhd

I need to install New-VHD cmdlet to use this command to create virtual disk and initilize them.

I have activated Hyper-V feature on Windows to be able to use this cmdlet, but i want to install only New-VHD cmdlet without Hyper-V. How can i do that?

Thank you

Comment: I think you should already have anything you need installed by activating the Hyper-V feature. Try `Import-Module Hyper-V` and should be good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn632582.aspx) just run (as admin): Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Feature Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management-PowerShell